# Convert lossless m4a to flac

Tags: sound, convert, flac, m4a

I tried to convert a file with `pacpl`, but I get the well-known "256" error.
With the `-v` flag, the FAQ of pacpl tells me:

> "The file you are trying to convert is a lossless .m4a file.  The
>   format is not yet supported by FAAC/FAAD."

Since faac/faad seems to be used in every other converting tool on Ubuntu, how can I successfully convert formats?

Comment: How is the lossless m4a a 24 bit sample? CD's are 16 bit, and SACD's are not rippable by any means, which means it was pointlessly "upconverted" to 24 bit, which is stupid.

Comment: @user126919 maybe they recorded it in 24bit.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can convert an m4a file to flac with the ffmpeg command-line tool:

To install ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

To convert:

```
ffmpeg -i filein.m4a -f flac fileout.flac
```

To batch convert:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.m4a"); do echo "Converting $i to flac"; ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:a flac "${i%.m4a}.flac"; done
```

Comment: works for me:) Hopefully the pacpl devs will fix the problem

Comment: ``     for file in *.m4a; do echo $file; ffmpeg -i "$file" -f flac "`basename "$file" .m4a`.flac"; done     `` To do a batch conversion of all *.m4a files in directory.

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo aptitude install libav-tools

for file in *.m4a; do avconv -i "$file" -f flac "`basename "$file" .m4a`.flac"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

While both the answers involving ffmpeg/avconv (which I think are essentially the same tool) both work, they currently have a flaw. Namely that lossless m4a is often 24 bit sample, and currently ffmpeg/avconv will generally force the conversion to end up in 16 bit sample.

I believe using sndfile-convert (libsndfile) does not have this problem. Likewise, I believe it can be avoided by using mplayer to decode the m4a before encoding it with ffmpeg or flac. I think soundKonverter on KDE may do this for you.

In any case, whatever you do, I suggest checking whether the original and the converted file have the same bit depth of samples.

Comment: But sndfile-convert can not read iTunes AAC-LC.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use this code. `for file in *.m4a; do fname=$(basename "$file" .m4a); ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -ar 48000 -f flac  "$fname".flac; done`.

So the output file don't have *.m4a.flac as extension.

And this is the ouput from `ffprobe` on a flac file:
*Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)*
And don't forget to check the tags/metadata on the file. I was surprised to see my mail address in the tag/metadata. And `ffprobe` show more mtag/metada as Easytag.

> thanks to zetdotpi and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664758

Comment: Also, conversion from m4a to flac does seem to lose a metadata picture that was written to the files.

Answer (score 0):

Just combining all the useful information from the other three answers.

To check the bit depth on your mp4 files:

```
# cd into desired directory then... 
ffprobe -show_streams ./[pick one file to test].m4a | grep -e codec_name -e bits_per_raw_sample
```

This should show the bit depth at the bottom of the output.

To use ffmpeg and for all files in a folder (assuming they are not 24 bit (or higher)):

```
# cd into desired directory then... 
for file in *.m4a ; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -f flac "$( basename "$file" .m4a ).flac" ; done
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Find all file with m4a extensions (works when filename as space or a new line) and convert codec using ffmpeg:

```
 find . -type f -name "*.m4a" -print0 | xargs -0 -I "{}" bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a flac "${1%.m4a}.flac"' _ "{}" \;
```